# What is the appropriate site for this question about designing a Java library?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

What is the right place for the following question? Stack Overflow? Software Engineering? Or another?

> I plan to write a library in java, consisting of packages A, B, C and so on. Every package encapsulates a part of the big picture. B relies on A, C on B and so on. For this purpose every package offers a single class to the next package. However, every package is optional in that the user can decide to substitute their own implementation. How do I construct the interfaces (concept, not java entity) between the packages?
>
> My first idea was to simply put an interface (java entity) and an implementing class into the package with lower ordinal number, i.e. interface AtoB and class AtoBImpl into A etc. However, if a user of the library does want to use package B but provide their own implementation for A, they not only have to import B.*, but also A.AtoB. While this may not be a big deal, it looks like a better solution might exist.
>
> My second idea was to create extra packages only for the interfaces, i.e. a package AtoB containing an interface AtoB. The implementation of that would still reside in A. A user using B but not A now has to import B.* and AtoB.*, but no references to A remain. This looks cleaner to me but also more unwieldy.
>
> My third idea was to put all interfaces into a common package, i.e. a package inter containing interfaces AtoB, BtoC etc.
>
> Is there a best practise? Or another, better approach? Am I splitting hairs? Thanks!

Comment: @programmer5000 not necessarily, see [Are Design Review questions on-topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6504/31260) at SE.SE meta. Recommended reading: **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: Thanks @programmer5000 for the quick answer!

Comment: Thanks @gnat for the insightful resources!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking about choosing between three software designs, which makes it a "software design" query.

So, this question would be more **on-topic in the Software Engineering site**, than in SO.